# Normalizing inline-block list item height

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="info-list">
<li class="info-item">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
        <img class="preview" src="/Image.png" />
    <div class="data-wrapper">
        Data
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Description
    </div>
</li>
<li class="info-item">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
        <img class="preview" src="/Image.png" />
    <div class="data-wrapper">
        Data
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Here is a description.  More description.  Very descriptive.
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the matching style:

```
.info-list{
text-align: center;
}

.info-item{
margin: 4px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: black;
}

.preview{
margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
float: left;
display: block;
width: 128px;
height: 128px;
}

.data-wrapper{
margin: 4px 0 4px 4px;
float: left;
width: 128px;
height: 128px;
}

.description{
clear: both;
width: 264px;
height: 100px;
}
```

The problem you will see is that the second element's height is equal with the first, but it is being propped up from the length of the content in the `div.description` element.  This can be fixed by applying `white-space: nowrap` to either the `div.description` or the `div.list-item` elements but this causes the `div.description` content to overflow to the right.  How can I fix this list?  I do not want to float the elements because I want them to be centered within the list, but the inline whitespace handling is causing issues for some reason even though the `div.description` elements are all the same height / width.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kap6quf6/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, so you can set it to middle or top for `.info-item` so that they align:

```
.info-item {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: lightgray;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kap6quf6/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix. Will accept when I am able.